# Django - Custom SQL in the connection string

Tags: python, sql, django, connection-string

I have had some issues with downtime as a result of hitting the `max_user_connections` limit in MySql.

The **default connection timeout is 8 hours**, so once we hit the limit (and having no access to kill the connections on our shared hosting) I simply had to wait 8 hours for the connections to time out.

I would like to add the following code to my connection string:

```
SET wait_timeout=300;
```

Which would **change the timeout to 5 minutes**. As you can imagine, I'm much happier to deal with 5 minutes of downtime than 8 hours. ;)

Is there a good way of adding **custom SQL to the connection string in django**?

If not, it has been suggested that we write some **middleware** that runs the SQL before the view is processed.

That might work, but I would feel more comfortable knowing that the query was absolutely **guaranteed to run for every connection**, even if more than one connection is opened for each view.

Thanks!

PS - before you tell me I should just hunt down the code that is keeping the connections from being closed - ***Never Fear!*** - we are doing that, but I would like to have this extra insurance against another 8 hour block of downtime

Comment: Are you not able to change the mySQL config?

Comment: maybe you mean "query string" instead of "connection string"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a list of commands to send to MySQL when the connection is open, by setting the DATABASE_OPTIONS dictionary in `settings.py`.

(Incidentally, note that Django doesn't open a new connection for every view.)

Comment: Good info! thanks so much this is exactly the solution I was hoping for :)